# django-tables2: template rendering with unicode

Tags: django, django-tables2

```
def html_decode(s):
    htmlCodes = (
            ("'", '&#39;'),
            [...]
            ('é', '&eacute;')
        )
    for code in htmlCodes:
        s = s.replace(code[1], code[0])
    return s

class WordsTable(tables.Table):
    [...]
    def render_bibl(self, value):
        return html_decode(value)
```

I am decoding that column because it cointains things like `&auml;` or `&eacute;`. When doing that, django-tables2 gives me the following error: `The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: ��`

Comment: try `return mark_safe(s)` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe

Comment: Are you using Python 2? If so, try using unicode e.g. `u'é'`.